# Computed property must have an explicit type when using didSet and long hand syntax ()

Tags: swift, generics, initialization, didset

This is good:

```
var strings:Array<String> = []
{
    didSet
    {
        println("did it")
    }
}
```

This gives a build error `Computed property must have an explicit type`:

```
var strings = Array<String>()
{
    didSet
    {
        println("did it")
    }
}
```

What is the correct syntax to combine the inferred type of the String Array using the longhand form `Array<String>()`, with a `didSet`?

Comment: Your second example compiles fine (and works as expected) in Xcode 6.3 beta 2 (build 6D532l), so this seems to be a bug in Xcode 6.1.1 that has been fixed already.

Comment: using Xcode 6.3 (6D520o) at present. Will try the latest...

Comment: With the official you can do `var strings:Array<String> = Array<String>...` and it compiles. DONT use the beta unless you like Segmentation Fault 11.